# Не видна переменная в функции

Tags: javascript, dom

Почему внутри функции ShowSlide не виден массив slides?
При первом вызове консол.лог размер выводится(выводит img).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: предоставте код вместо скриншота

Comment: разобрался почему так работало.

Comment: Чтобы функция `ShowSlide` вызывалась при клике, должно быть так: `.addEventListener("click", ShowSlide);`

Answer (score 1):

ShowSlide вызывался сразу во время бинда на клик.
Убрал вызов .addEventListener("click", ShowSlide); 
и работает так как требовалось.

---

мало ли кому-то потребуется...-_-

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно добавить код с `querySelectorAll` внутрь функции `ShowSlide()` или передать необходимые значение через параметры функции `ShowSlide()`.